# How to solve BeamDeprecationWarning in Apache-Beam

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

First,
Code for storing data in google cloud platform bigQuery tables after generating simple data.
Imported Apache-Beam library and used it.
Runner used Google Cloud Platform Dataflow.

Here code.

```
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import apache_beam as beam

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
     project='project-id',
     runner='runner',
     temp_location='bucket-location'
)
def pardo_dofn_methods(test=None):
   import apache_beam as beam 
 class testFunction(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        result = element.split(',')

        testing = {'test_column': result[0], 'test_column2': result[1], 'test_column3': result[2],
                       'test_column4': result[3]}
        return [testing]

    def finish(self):
        print('finish')

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
  results = (
      pipeline
      | 'Generating data' >> beam.Create([
          'test1,test2,test3,test4'
          'test5,test6,test7,test8'
       ])
      | beam.ParDo(testFunction())
      | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            'project-id:bigQuery-dataset.table-name',
            schema='test_column:STRING, test_column2:STRING, test_column3:STRING, test_column4:STRING',
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
      )
  )
```

pardo_dofn_methods()

It works well when run it.
However, there are two warnings:

```
BeamDeprecationWarning: options is deprecated since First stable release. References to <pipeline>.options will not be supported
 experiments = p.options.view_as(DebugOptions).experiments or []

BeamDeprecationWarning: BigQuerySink is deprecated since 2.11.0. Use WriteToBigQuery instead.
kms_key=self.kms_key))
```

I don't know why there is a warning.
Thank you.

Comment: Apparently there is an ongoing issue regarding the first warning, you can find it [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7686). Now, about the BigQuerySink warning, since you are actually using `WriteToBigQuery()`, could you updated your Apache Beam's version with `pip install --upgrade apache-beam[gcp] `. After performing the update, can you tell me if the second warning disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

The deprecation warning **"BigQuerySink is deprecated since 2.11.0. Use WriteToBigQuery instead."** is no longer displayed when I tested WriteToBigQuery() using `apache-beam==2.31.0` and runners **DataflowRunner** and **DirectRunner**. Thus this should not be displayed when using version 2.31.0 onwards.

The deprecation warning **"options is deprecated since First stable release. References to .options will not be supported"** is still shown as long as `options` is defined (see [github reference](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/pipeline.py#L234)) to provide warning on users.