# Apache Beam 2.31 deprecation warning while running Dataflow pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

While running my Dataflow pipeline,I am getting below warning message-
"options is deprecated since First stable release. References to .options will not be supported"
There is a relevant thread for this question but the answer is not satisfactory.
[How to solve BeamDeprecationWarning in Apache-Beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63431893/how-to-solve-beamdeprecationwarning-in-apache-beam)

The strange thing is that, I am not making any reference to options in my code, still getting the warning.

Can anyone advise on this? Is it possible that it is a general warning, which needs not to be considered.

please find the code below. Also python version used 3.6 and Apache Beam version tested on 2.31 and 2.32

```
#! /c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions

op=PipelineOptions()
op.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming=False
op.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).temp_location='gs://tempDir/temp'
op.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).project='beam'
op.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).job_name='dataflow-file-bq'
op.view_as(StandardOptions).runner='DataflowRunner'
op.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).region='asia-east2'
op.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).service_account_email='kk504685@gmail.com'
op.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).dataflow_kms_key='project/beam/locations/asia-east2/keyRings/computeEngine/cryptoKeys/computeEngine'
op.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).staging_location='gs://stgDir/stg'

p1=beam.Pipeline(options=op)

#this function is used to convert delimited records into json format
def to_json(csv_str):
 fields=csv_str.split('#')
 json_str={
    "field1":fields[0],
    "field2":fields[1],
    "field3":fields[2],
    "field4":fields[3],
    "field5":fields[4]
   }
 return json_str
 
fileToBQ=(
 p1
 |beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://sourceDir/data.dsv')
 |beam.Map(to_json)
 |beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
 'beam:dataset1.table1')
) 

p1.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a fix pending on beam side, warnings are not due to the code but due to core sdk itself! In the source code, it is referencing to pipeline options, hence the warnings.